# CreateSqlQuery doesn't retrieve scalar value in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

Why does `codigoUnificacion` variable is always null?

```
public int? GetCodigoUnificacionFamiliar(IList<Pariente> parientes)
        {
            List<string> cedulas = new List<string>();

            parientes.ToList().ForEach(p => cedulas.Add(p.Cedula));

            int? codigoUnificacion = Session
                .CreateSQLQuery(@"SELECT DISTINCT
                                            sa_bec_mtc_doc as Codigo
                                    FROM    sa_bec_matricula
                                            INNER JOIN sa_matricula ON sa_bec_matricula.sa_mtc_num = sa_matricula.sa_mtc_num
                                            INNER JOIN sa_alumno ON sa_matricula.sa_alu_cod = sa_alumno.sa_alu_cod
                                            INNER JOIN sa_periodo ON sa_matricula.sa_per_cod = sa_periodo.sa_per_cod
                                            INNER JOIN sa_tpo_beca ON sa_bec_matricula.sa_tpo_bec_cod = sa_tpo_beca.sa_tpo_bec_cod
                                    WHERE   sa_alu_ced IN (:cedulas)
                                            AND sa_per_abi = 1
                                            AND sa_tpo_bec_gpr = 2")
                .SetParameterList("cedulas", cedulas)
                .UniqueResult() as int?;

            return codigoUnificacion;
        }
```

Comment: What happens when you run that SQL directly against your database? Are you getting a Nullable<int> (e.g. int?) back? Are you running against SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, ...?

Comment: I agree with Spender Ruport. You're defeating the reason to use NHibernate. Also, please post your models.

Comment: Thank you for the answers.  I will try to implement using Criteria Objects.

Comment: Just to respond to some of the questions on why you would do this (execute SQL directly instead of criteria or linq).  You can't always map out every relationship in NHibernate.  Plus, there are queries that nhibernate simply cannot make (geography indexes, Hierarchy queries, complex aggregations, etc).  Those require straight sql.

Answer (score 11):

When Execute Queries that Return Scalar Values in NHibernate

**This will work!**

```
var max = session.CreateSQLQuery(query).UniqueResult();
decimal s = max != null ? Decimal.Parse(max.ToString()) : -1;
```

**This will return null !!!**

```
decimal? s = session.CreateSQLQuery(query).UniqueResult() as decimal?;
```

**This will not compile**

Because only reference or nullable types are accepted

```
decimal s = session.CreateSQLQuery(query).UniqueResult() as decimal;
```

**TypeConversionException**

Exception is thrown from NHibernate

```
decimal s = (decimal)session.CreateSQLQuery(query).UniqueResult();
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using var, you can define the type you are expecting.

**Example**

```
int max = session.CreateSQLQuery(query).UniqueResult<int>();
```

This way you don't have to try and apply a cast after the fact.